# Spurious "Process List" output on Start-Process

Tags: powershell

Within a ps1 script I have the following:

```
Write-Host "MySqlDump Running"
$runProg = "C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.4/bin/mysqldump.exe"
$runArgs = "JcTest --user=JcTest --password=JcTestPass --databases=TRUE --host=localhost --port=23246"
Start-Process -FilePath $runProg -ArgumentList $runArgs -RedirectStandardOutput "backup.sql" -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow
Write-Host "MySqlDump Finished"

backupFolder "C:\Backups" # A routine in a .psm1 module to create a 7Zip of a complete folder
```

On execution, the console output looks like this:

```
[C:\...\JCPrompt]> .\backupProj.ps1
MySqlDump Running

 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
      7     3.47       6.05       0.02   29524   1 mysqldump
MySqlDump Finished


7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21
      5     0.73       3.18       0.00   25332   1 7za
[C:\...\JcPrompt]> Scanning the drive:
367 folders, 1313 files, 92447874 bytes (89 MiB)
```

A spurious process list seems to be mixed in with the console output. Also notice a PS prompt in the middle of the 7zip output. This immediately appears upon execution of the `Start-Process` call.

Finally, this script also require an `<enter>` to finally return to the PS prompt.

Any clues would be most welcome!

Source for backup folder:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string]$folderName
)

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

$folderCurrent = (Get-Location).Path + "\"

Set-Location $folderName
$folderBase = (Get-Location).Path + "\"
$folderName = $folderBase.Split("\" )[-2]

Do_dsBackup ($folderBase + "*.*") ( $pathBackups + "\" + $folderName + '-' + (Get-dsShortDate))

Set-Location $folderCurrent

----------

function Do_dsBackup ( [String]$7zipSrc, [String]$7zipDest)
{
    if (-not $7zipSrc.StartsWith('"')) { $7zipSrc = Get-dsQuoted( $7zipSrc) }
    if (-not $7zipDest.StartsWith('"')) { $7zipDest = Get-dsQuoted( $7zipDest) }

    Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput=".\NUL" -FilePath "c:\4dos\7za.exe" -ArgumentList "a -r -y", $7zipDest, $7zipSrc
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `backupFolder` also calls `Start-Process` and forgets to discard output from it

Comment: bacckupFolder looks like this: ;`Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow -FilePath "c:\4dos\7za.exe" -ArgumentList "a -r -y", $7zipDest, $7zipSrc`

I added `-RedirectStandardOutput=".\NUL"` to no effect.

Comment: If you don't want the process instances listed in the output, simply remove the `-PassThru` switches (or make sure you assign the output to a variable)

Comment: Removing `-Passthru` from both `Start-Process` calls fixed the output problem. the extra <Enter> to get the PS prompt back persists :(

Add the `-Passthru` comment as a reply, and I will give accepted answer :)

Comment: Please [post the full source code in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64699187/edit) of `backupFolder` if you want help figuring out why

Comment: Original question edited with source.